# How to get status bar height in overlay window context for Android?

Tags: android, android-statusbar

Following code will get a warning:

```
Using internal inset dimension resource `status_bar_height` is not supported
```

```kotlin
val statusBarHeight: Int  
    get() {  
            var result = 0  
            val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android")  
            if (resourceId > 0) {  
                result = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)  
            }  
            retur result  
    }
```

Is there a public API to get it (not from activity)?